# Install & configure MAME for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to install MAME and a frontend GUI (like gmameui), but I cannot find any guide on how to do it properly, because I know from past experience that setting everything and make it work is not that easy.
I downloaded and installed the files for the MAME from http://sdlmame.wallyweek.org/download/ , now I'm trying to find the gmameui deb package but I couldn't find anything so far.
Where can I find that package? Can you link me a guide on how to set up everything on Ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to install the following 2 packages:

```
sudo apt-get install mame mame-tools
```

That will do it.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is gnome-video-arcade.  Also, there are a few steps needed.  In my case, my mame dir is 400G so it wont fit on ssd.  I created a symlink from the mame dir on my big drive to ~/.mame.   Also, there is a /etc/mame/mame.ini that needs to be edited to point to the proper directories.  Once that is done, you should just run gnome-video-arcade and it will catalog your roms.

The important part is make sure that all the files are in the proper subdir in your mame directory.

Hope that helps.